# Is there a way to use module/2 in ECLiPSe Prolog?

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

In SWI-Prolog, I am using code such as at the beginning
of a module text file:

```
:- module(foo, [bar/2]).
:- use_module(library(jack)).
```

**I don't want to change my code**. How can I neverthelss use
ECLiPSe Prolog (*). Is there some library that defines a 
`module/2` directive in ECLiPSe Prolog?

Best Regards

(*)
http://eclipseclp.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code defines a macro that maps module/2 into module/3 directives:

```
:- export macro((:-)/1, translate_directive/2, [top_only]).
translate_directive(
    (:- module(Module, Exports)),
    (:- module(Module, Exports, [swi]))
).
```

Compile (or import) this before compiling the module written for SWI.  Note that the 3rd argument of module/3 must contain a *language module*, corresponding to the dialect your module is written in.  I have used `swi` here, other choices would be `quintus`, `iso` or ECLiPSe's native `eclipse_language`.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile Prolog module that uses SWI-Prolog module system using Logtalk for use with ECLiPSe (or any other of the supported Prolog compilers, including those that don't provide a module system).

Comment: Prolog modules that start with a `module/2` directive are compiled by Logtalk as objects with the export list being interpreted as public resources. I.e. the `module/2` directive it's already supported. No need to define it. See http://logtalk.org/manuals/userman/migration.html#migration_compiling

Answer (score 0):

No, there are only `module/1` and `module/3`.

You an see the list of all what available here: http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/fullindex.html

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog (an others) `module/2` directives can be replaced on ECLiPSe by `module/1` + `export/1` directives as you likely already found out. Also both SWI-Prolog and ECLiPSe support conditional compilation directives and the `dialect` flag. This should provide you with another alternative (not tested) for using the same Prolog files with both systems:

```
:- if(current_prolog_flag(dialect, swi)).

    :- module(foo, [p/1]).

:- elif(current_prolog_flag(dialect, eclipse)).

    :- module(foo).
    :- export(p/1).

:- else.

    ...

:- endif.
```

Comment: Would a call to prolog_load_context(dialect, ...) be more correct? In case the above is part of a client code, that can change the dialect? Probably not needed since module/[1,2] are supposed to be some of the earlier steps in loading a Prolog text.

Comment: The `prolog_load_context/2` predicate is usually called from the term-expansion predicates. So, yes, it could be used for a solution similar to the one posted by Joachim. But this is far from an universal predicate. It would be preferable to check the value of the `dialect` de facto standard Prolog flag using the standard `current_prolog_flag/2` predicate.