# How can I freely assert/retract facts with modules in ECLiPSe Prolog?

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I am trying to run the following test case:

```
test :- assertz(abc : uvw(1)).
```

The above works in SWI-Prolog. But I am having problems
in making it work in ECLiPSe Prolog. I am getting the
following error:

```
trying to redefine an existing imported procedure in assertz(abc : uvw(1))
```

I didn't import abc:uvw/1, neither does it exist. Any
flags around that would allow to run test/0 successfully
in ECLiPSe Prolog?

Best Regards

Edit:
P.S.: The following phrasing does also not work:

```
test :- abc : assertz(uvw(1)).
```

One then only gets the following error message:

```
lookup module does not exist in abc : assertz(uvw(1)) in module eclipse
```

Comment: did you tried `test :- abc : assertz(uvw(1)).` ?

Comment: See new edit of the question. Does also not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECLiPSe uses the @-annotation to specify the context module for a predicate:

```
test :- assertz(uvw(1)) @ abc.
```

See also http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/control/A-2.html

Comment: I cannot use @ if I use module/3 with [swi]. I get `syntax error: postfix/infix operator expected` when I use the syntax operator.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you want to do some kind of benchmarking, in which case you should not use any compatibility layers as they could distort the result.

Comment: Yes exactly, since I want to go single source. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592791/is-there-a-way-to-use-module-2-in-eclipse-prolog . I thought macros are applied at compile time, so shouldn't cause some distortion. But maybe, who knows...?